# React Native Android deep linking url not passed through

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I've got deep linking to work on a basic level with our React native app using the excellent tutorial at https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e. Works a treat on iOS, however on Android I don't seem to get the url passed back when it links back into my app:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (UtilsCommon.isNative) {
      RNSplashScreen.hide();
      if (UtilsCommon.isIos) {
        Linking.addEventListener("url", this.handleOpenURL);
      } else {
        console.log("registering deep linking on Android");
        Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
          console.log("url", url);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener("url", this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = event => {
    console.log(event.url);
  };
```

So on iOS, the link back from the test page happily goes into handleOpenURL and I see the entire url that was linked to come out in the console. However, on Android, we always get url as being null. So whilst it re-opens the app, I can't determine where it should go due to this. I added the following intent to AppManifest.xml:

```
    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I've tried specifying an android:host attribute inside of the data node, but the url still stubbornly remained null. Can anyone tell me what else I need to do?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, how did you solved it? I'm facing this similar issue on RN v0.59.8.